# Model runs on jupyter notebook but fails when imported on android

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

```java
btPredict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img,200,200,true);
        try {
            Model model = Model.newInstance(getApplicationContext());
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 200, 200, 3},
                                                                      DataType.FLOAT32);
            TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
            tensorImage.load(img);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            Model.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();
            textView.setText(outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0] + " \n"+ outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[1]);
            model.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error

```
021-04-30 11:55:07.70329735-29735/com.example.catsdogmodel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.example.catsdogmodel, PID: 29735
     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
         at com.example.catsdogmodel.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7869)
         at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14958)
         at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7838)
         at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29362)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)][1]
```

[image: IDE]

Comment: Nothing? No explanation of what fails? No error message? We just have to guess? You need to provide some more info for us to be able to guess what goes wrong.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i have uploaded the error.

Comment: The value returned from `getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer` returns a FloatArray with only 1 element. You're trying to reference index 0 and then index 1, the latter will fail.

Comment: @blagerweij your answers gives me this error Array type expected; found: '@org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull float' but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your model, I'm pretty sure it's this line `textView.setText(outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0] + " \n"+ outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[1]);`
Maybe your output is wrapped once more than you think, so you have to write `textView.setText(outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0][0] + " \n"+ outputFeature0.getFloatArray()[0][1]);`
But that is hard to say without knowing your model structure. In addition to that, I would not create all your input data and the model in the `onClick` method but rather in a separate class.